# Is it possible to scale an image proportionally both on width and height based on a fixed container?

Tags: html, css, image-scaling

Suppose we have an image that is 400x200 and another that is 200x400 and I want them to fit in a 200x200 box so the first should be scaled to 200x100 and the second to 100x200

We won't know the dimensions of the images in advance.

[edit] Plenty of good answers, thank you all!

Comment: I'm not sure a 200x100 and 100x200 would fit in a 200x200 box...

Comment: @JamesDouglas yeah they won't fill the container what I want is to get them scaled proportionally so they fit and don't get distorted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

```
img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t75cxqt0/2/**

Comment: Brilliant, I'd considered a similar fix using `background-size`, but that would involve moving the image `src` into the CSS, which is hardly ideal. Unfortunately IE is the weak link here (although Edge is due to support it in v16): http://www.caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Answer (score 1):

Set both of these:

```
max-width: 200px;
max-height: 200px;
```

That will keep allow the images to resize automatically to a maximum of 200px on either side.

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  
  /* just for demo purposes*/
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x400/000/fff" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out elsewere, you could use `max-height` and `max-width`, which is good. But I'd like to take it a step further, and make it so that it doesn't matter what the container size is.
Use a percentage value instead of `200px`:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.piprd.com/images/400X200.gif">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x400/">
</div>
```

To prove this works, I have written some code (unnecessary for your actual code). You just need to enter the desired width + height for the container, and you can see the effect!

```js
function size() {
  var width = prompt("Please enter width for container", "200px");
  var height = prompt("Please enter height for container", "200px");
  if (width != null) {
    $('.container').css('width', width);
  }
  if (height != null) {
    $('.container').css('height', height);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="float: right;" onclick="size()">Choose size values</button>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.piprd.com/images/400X200.gif">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x400/">
</div>
```