# Automatically resizing images when the browser width/height changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a page with many images in divs and the layout looks good only in full size, when the browser window is smaller it's really messy. I found a similar question on stack overflow but their answers don't work for my case.

EDIT: I did everything what you guys advised but it still doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body background="">

  <head>
    <style>
      div.asciigun {
         top: 30%;
         left: 50%;
         position: absolute;
         max-width: 100%;
  
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="asciigun">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTU7ROirglSjKnpsLvt29uCDlVtpZutirtiXyg3FF0UtXFf0TnE" height="90%" width="90%" >
      </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>` in the head section of your html page?

Comment: I just added it but the image still doesn't go smaller proportionally

Comment: set width in % of all cases. every where width should be in percentages. your window with is 100% then find the images width in % according to you.

Comment: You can also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766418/is-it-possible-to-scale-an-image-proportionally-both-on-width-and-height-based-o)

Comment: You aren't closing your img tag and there is a random `</a>` after it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try another approach. Try not to modify `max-width` or `max-height`. Just leave it as it is (or set `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`).

And then change `<img src="url.jpg">` to `background: url("url.jpg");` and then just do

```
.image {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

or

```
.image {
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: what happens to the div? I did something wrong here

Comment: <head>
<style>

div.image {
    background-size: cover;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="image">
<background: url("https://78.media.tumblr.com/a754187de32b0e20f8efc10a480970e2/tumblr_pbazjnoOjh1x5vw3ao1_500.gif");  height="500" width="275"></background:>
.image {
    background-size: cover;
}


</div>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out! I needed viewport value instead of %. Now images go proportionally with browser size and stay in place.

```
div.asciigun {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30vw;
    left: 74vw;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 15vw;
}
```